# curl php script always showing failed result when checking

Tags: php, dom, curl

hi there i am using the follwoing code to check html source code for specified text and return fail of success but i am always getting failed even though i am using correct login heres my code i am using with my curl script 
      }

```
    if(isset($_POST['mp'], $_POST['delim'], $_POST['submit'])){
    $mps = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['mp']);
    foreach($mps as $mp){
        $mp = explode($_POST['delim'], $mp);
        $email = $mp[0];
        $password = $mp[1];

        $html = checkmail($email, $password);
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($html);
        $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
        $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

        if($title == "Sorry, but we couldn't sign you in"){
            echo "<br />FAILED - Email: $email - Password: $password";
        }else{
            echo "<br />SUCCESS - Email: $email - Password: $password";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

> object(DOMElement)#3 (18) { ["tagName"]=> string(5) "title" ["schemaTypeInfo"]=> NULL ["nodeName"]=> string(5) "title" ["nodeValue"]=> string(9) "Tesco.com" ["nodeType"]=> int(1) ["parentNode"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["firstChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["lastChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["previousSibling"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["nextSibling"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["attributes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["ownerDocument"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["namespaceURI"]=> NULL ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["localName"]=> string(5) "title" ["baseURI"]=> NULL ["textContent"]=> string(9) "Tesco.com" } NULL

Comment: That's the first post I see here without "hi there" cutted out

Comment: well can u help instead off just commenting something useless

Comment: That's an XSS attack waiting to happen.  Be sure that you are escaping arbitrary data for HTML by using `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: brad i dont wuite understand

Answer (score 0):

Why does it looks like some kind of brute force script? Anyway, I guess that problem lays on that `$title-main` is undeclared.

In

```
if($title-main == "Sorry, but we couldn't sign you in"){
```

you should do:

```
if($title == "Sorry, but we couldn't sign you in"){
```

Comment: i changed it but still just coming up with success instead of failing false login

Comment: Try to `var_dump($title)` before `if`. Maybe it will reveal something.

Comment: that just causes this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in  on line 33

Comment: See this: http://pastebin.com/NY9sapiM (**updated link**). I guess you forgot semicolon.

Comment: i get this string(9) "Tesco.com" 
SUCCESS - Email: email@domain.com - Password: password

Comment: <title>Tesco.com - Sorry, but we couldn't sign you in that what i am looking to get the script to recognise

Comment: So... if you get "Tesco.com" and it goes to `else`, then... it runs like it should.

Comment: no i need it to get this string Tesco.com - Sorry, but we couldn't sign you and not just tesco.com as both the success and fail page have tesco.com

Comment: Could you `var_dump($nodes->item(0));` and update your question?

Comment: put above `var_dump` before your `if` statement, edit your question at the top of this page using 'edit' link, and paste what `var_dump` produced there.

Comment: heres the source code to the failed login page could u halep me fix my script and get it so say fail when it reaches this page and success if it goes any where else http://pastebin.com/15VvnYVk source code

Comment: It looks like 'Tesco.com' is the title of the page, while rest of the title that you're looking for is inserted using JavaScript.

Comment: is there i way i can check the java script instead is there any way i can get this to work

Comment: If it's JavaScript - as far as I know, you can't.